# For which $u$ does the derivative $f'(u,0)$ of $f(x,y)=xy/(x^2+y^2)$ exist?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by setting**

**$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}&(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\0 & (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$**
**(a) For which vectors $u\ne 0$ does $f'(0; u)$ exist? Evaluate it when it
exists.**

**(b) Do $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ exist at $0$?**

**(c) Is $f$ differentiable at $0$?**

**(d) Is $f$ continuous at $0$?**

I have thought a lot about this problem: for (a), let $u\neq 0$ and $u=(h,k)$ then $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(o+tu)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(0+t(h,k))-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{hk}{t(h^2+k^2)}$ and so this limit exists if $h=0$ or $k=0$.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to "compact" your title.

Comment: By considering $u=(h,h)$ and $u=(h,0)$, you'll be able to give a negative answer to (d), so as (c).

Comment: Both f(u, 0) and f(0, y) are identically 0.  The derivatives at (0, 0) are 0,

Comment: @JeanMarie Is my reasoning right to answer (a)?

Comment: Why don't you use $(\partial f/\partial x, \partial f/\partial y)$ instead of $f'(u,v)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I am studying from the book "Analysis on Manifold" by Munkres and he uses the notation that I use, I do not know other notations because I am just beginning to study vector analysis.

Comment: @user247327 I could say that since the directional derivative of $f$ in $0$ with respect to $u=(1,1)$ does not exist then the function is not differentiable in $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) Let $h= \in \Bbb{R}$ then $f(h,0)=f(0,h)=0$ so from this you can deduce that the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are zero.

d) Take the paths $(t,t)$ as $t \to 0$ and $(t,0)$ as $t \to 0$ and from these paths you will find different limits when approaching $(0,0)$, so you functions is not continuous at $(0,0)$ thus not differentiable at $(0,0)$

$\text{EDIT}$

Paths are curves, where in this case they pass through the point $(0,0)$.

If a limit exists then it is unique,thus uniqueness is a necessary condition for the existence of a limit at a given point.

If the limit of a function at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ exists then it will have the same value $l$ for every path we choose to approach the point $(x_0,y_0)$

So in this case the curves $g(t)=(t,t) \to (0,0)$ as $t \to 0$ and $h(t)=(t,0) \to (0,0)$ as $t \to 0$.

You can see this as approaching the origin from $\text{x-axis}$ namely where $y=0$ and $x$ varies,or approaching the origin from the diagonal,namely the line $y=x$

But these two approaches give two different results for the value of  $l$ thus the limit does not exist.

Comment: Please be more clear with your response. Explain everything please.

Comment: When you refer to paths this is understood as vectors directors?

Comment: @Nash i edited...if you want more help let me know.